ASTRO / SendGrid - Redirecting when sending is successful or gives error
I have an issue with Astro.redirect. It constantly gives me an error: "AstroError [ResponseSentError]: The response has already been sent to the browser and cannot be altered"
I just want to redirect to another pages with Astro.redirect when a message is sent or gives an error with the POST method.
`
---
import sendGrid from "@sendgrid/mail";

sendGrid.setApiKey(import.meta.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
    try {
        // Getting posted data from our contact form
        const data = await Astro.request.formData();
        const name= data.get("name");
        const email = data.get("email");
        const text= data.get("text");

        // Sending email
        const msg = {
            to: emailDestination, // Change to your recipient
            from: "mail@domain.com", // Change to your verified sender
            subject: "Subject",
            text: "Mytext"
        };
        await sendGrid
            .send(msg)
            .then((response) => {
                Astro.redirect("/success");
                console.error(response[0].statusCode);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

---


Pretty sure you're not showing the whole code for that page (or perhaps there's a middleware?). The error means that you already told the browser to render a page by sending some HTML (or response headers) and now it's too late to change your mind and tell it to redirect.

Fixed in the answer

If someone read this and is still interested, I managed to fix the issue like this and it work's for me:
---
import sendGrid from "@sendgrid/mail";
import blacklist from "../data/blacklist.json";

sendGrid.setApiKey(import.meta.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const recaptchaKey = import.meta.env.RECAPTCHA_KEY_API.toString();
const emailDestination = import.meta.env.EMAIL_DESTINATION.toString();
let success = false;
let responseCode = null;
let blackListFlag = false;

if (Astro.request.method === "POST") {
    try {
        const data = await Astro.request.formData();
        const name= data.get("namee");
        const email = data.get("email");

        // Sending email
        const msg = {
            to: emailDestination, // Change to your recipient
            from: "email@email.com", // Change to your verified sender
            subject: "Subject",
            text: `Your text`,
        };

        for (let index = 0; index < blacklist.emails.length; index++) {
            if (blacklist.emails[index].email == email) {
                blackListFlag = true;
            }
        }
        if (blackListFlag === false) {
            await sendGrid
                .send(msg)
                .then((response) => {
                    // console.error(response[0].statusCode);
                    responseCode = response[0].statusCode;
                    success = true;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log(email);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
---


Then in an script, I detect the success and responseCode variables to redirect to another page:

<script define:vars={{ success, responseCode }}>
    if (success === true) {
        window.location.replace(
            "/result?code=" + responseCode,
            (replace = true),
        );
    }
</script>

